# PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions doesn't open Facebook after iOS9 update

Tags: objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login, ios9

I've updated to iOS9, and now my Facebook login button, which calls:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] block:^(PFUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {...}
```

doesn't even attempt to open Facebook.

I've added the necessary files to my info.plist file ([as suggested here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)), which now looks like this:

[image]

But the FB app doesn't launch, and the block is never called. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem , you solve this  ?

Comment: It started working, but I'm not sure why... I deleted and re-installed the pods, cleaned data, reinstalled my app. I tried using other login methods, and then reverting back to this one. I don't know what fixed it in the end. Oh and I also added fbauth to the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes (as opposed to just fbauth2).

Comment: I try to re-installed the Facebook sdk , but still not works )-:

Comment: My problem was the time and date was not tuned , after I set time and date to automatically everything work (-;

Comment: Ah yeah, I think I actually restored my phone from a backup, and then it worked. I also recall there being some time/date issue as Roei mentioned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (Parse) Facebook login in iOS9 by default will use Facebook in the safari browser instead of the Facebook App as this is now regarded as the best user experience.

If the click on the login button does not take you to Safari, you should check if you've updated the SDKs for Facebook and Parse as well as the changeds to the plist already described.