# Facebook sdk 4.6 and PFFacebookUtils 1.8.5 login open webview although Facebook app is install on My device

Tags: facebook-sdk-4.0, pffacebookutils

I update My Facebook sdks to 4.6 and Parse to 1.8.5 , and after that I notice that in iOS 7,8 in login the app is go to Facebook app for premmisions and in iOS 9 the app go to safari.

And I try to add setLoginBehavior before  logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions but it did not solve the problems.

```
[[PFFacebookUtils facebookLoginManager] setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount];


NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"user_friends", nil];
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
 {
}];
```

what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

scbojer says:

> The (Parse) Facebook login in iOS9 by default will use Facebook in the safari browser instead of the Facebook App as this is now regarded as the best user experience.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32710449/1180974

I am having the same problem, and I completely disagree with this "best user experience" argument.  I have not found any workaround for the moment either.

Comment: I downgrade My Facebook sdks to 4.5.1 files and keek the xml in P.list  that need to add in sdks 4.6 and it work grate !

Comment: That's just terrible... Who would sign in on Safari when you have the app installed?